# Visual C++ Compiler error 2061

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++, dialog, compiler-errors

I am new to Visual C++ so please don't bite my head off. I can't figure out why I am getting this error. I have added an include of Parts.h in my Form1.h and I believe I have the correct code to call it. If anyone could help me to put this right I would be grateful.

This is the error:

```
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Parts'  c:\users\*********\documents\visual studio 2005\projects\machinev.2\machinev.2\Form1.h  116
```

This is the code:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 Parts ^Parts = gcnew Parts();
                 Parts->ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Parts^ parts = gcnew Parts();
parts->ShowDialog();
```

Don't use the same name for class and variable.

Comment: Thank you very much. I should of known this as it's very basic, thank you very much though.